# Android: Where are database files stored?

Tags: database, android, sqlite

I created a SQLite database on Android device. The program can read/write to database so the database file has obviously been created. The SQLiteDatabase.mPath is set to

```
db.mPath = "/data/data/dev.client.android/databases/clientDB.db"
```

but when I browse the directories on the device I can't locate the file clientDB.db. I looked inside data directory  but it appears to be empty.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you mean you visited `/data` and found nothing in it, and you are examining an ordinary piece of Android hardware, that is expected. DDMS does not have permission to browse through `/data`.

However, at least if your app is compiled in debug mode, you can use the `adb pull` command at the console to download your file directly.

Comment: In my device file manager I searched `filename.sqlite` but I get no result ? Can you tell why ?

Comment: @VivekWarde: You cannot browse internal storage on a production device.

Comment: so where can I see my sqlite database other than assets folder

Comment: @VivekWarde: The simplest solution is to run some tests on an emulator, where you *can* browse `/data`.

Answer (score 34):

try getDatabasePath on ContextWrapper ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html ).  If you are in an Activity or Application class try:

```
File dbFile = getDatabasePath(MY_DB_NAME);
Log.i(dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Just assuming its in `/data/data/my.package.name/databases/` is bad as there is no guarantee the data has not been moved to the SD card or the device/OS has just decided on a different data directory.

Answer (score 6):

In debug mode you can use **adb shell** and browse the directory content. In the shell you can call **sqlite3 /data/data/dev.client.android/databases/clientDB.db** to analyse the DB.

Comment: I tried typing this in the Terminal tab in Android Studio while the app was being debugged but it didn't recognize the command. The app's directory on my computer was the path in the console. Is this where I should be inputting it?