# Get SQLite file on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to access the sqlite file on my android phone running ICS, of an application that I have developed but the data directory is empty. Any ideas on where is it and how to access it? I would like to have a look on the tables and their values to ensure that everything works properly.

Answer (score 2):

it is stored in \data\data\PACKAGENAME\databasefile

But unless your phone is rooted, you won't be able to access that directory

Comment: It is not rooted. /data contains only shared_prefs directory

Comment: that's correct. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105219/android-where-are-database-files-stored). I am sure there are existing code to let you export the database and examine it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a real device than it has to be rooted, but if you run it in the emulator you will have root access and can obtain the files you need.