# Create SQLlite connection with C# on connected Android device

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, usb

I have connected my android device to my system using a USB cable. Now I want to reach a database which I use in my project on the device. From here I want retrieve data into my system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly because of the security on Android devices

If your device is rooted, you can copy it directly out of the application database folder onto your computer. 
If you want to connect to the database on a non-rooted device, you are going to have to backup the database to a folder on the device and then copy it down to your computer.

IF however you are on a rooted device that allows USB access like a normal folder structure (my non-rooted ICS S2 does not allow this anymore), then you should be able to connect to the folder directly: 
[Android: Where are database files stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105219/android-where-are-database-files-stored)